# Macros from linux kernel code

Tags: c, linux, macros, linux-kernel

I found belows code in linux kerel code at http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/include/asm/io.h?v=3.1;a=arm

```
#define __raw_readl(a)          (__chk_io_ptr(a), *(volatile unsigned int __force   *)(a))
```

I am unable to understand it. How does it work. I know it used to read some bytes from mapped device memory but can not understand how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work the following way:

1. Call the `__chk_io_ptr(a)` in order to check the memory available
2. Read `unsigned int` from memory by dereferencing the pointer.

I suppose you use this macro the following way:

```
unsigned int data = __raw_readl(a);
```

By preprocessor it is replaced by:

```
unsigned int data =  (__chk_io_ptr(a), *(volatile unsigned int __force   *)(a));
```

So as result of the comma operator in `data` stored `unsigned long` value pointed by `a`.

**EDIT:** The `__chk_io_ptr(a)` seems to be a macro in accordance to [this](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/compiler.h#L35).

```
#define __chk_io_ptr(x) (void)0
```

That actually does nothing.

Comment: so whats the need of using (,) i mean coma operator here?

Comment: @Mr.32 possibly in past/future there is a function that actually checks the memory for availability. So, comma operator allows to make a sequence of calls/actions. If you will remove it, you will get a compilation error.